# PHP: Unwanted text stripping

Tags: php, stripping

I've been encountering this problem for a while now and I have no idea how to solve it. There is this "guestbook" that I made where people write a message and it prints out under the form. So a normal guestbook. But it sometimes strips messages from a certain point onward. Let me explain - they write something like ***"It was amazing, incredible, awesome performance, that should be repeated more and more."*** and the guestbook shows only ***"It was amazing, incredible, awesome performance"***. I have no idea what is wrong with the code nor what characters make this happen, but every now and then I see incomplete messages with a following message that says something like "The message was not send completely." and then summarizing of their previous stripped one.

```
nl2br(addslashes(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['message']))))
```

This is the code that I use for editing messages before inputting them into the database. I took a look into the database and the messages are already stripped, so there is probably a problem with sending or editing the message rather than with printing it out of the database.

People are able to write full paragraphs that end up unstripped, so it's not a problem that occurs to everyone and everytime. There are currently about 50 messages and only 2 of them are stripped, so the stripped ones make like 4% of them all. Are there any characters that the people might eventually be using that cause the unwanted stripping? May there be a problem on the users' side? Or is there a problem with my code?

Thanks for help and any ideas in advance.

Comment: just log exactly what you get from server as $_POST and you will see what is the problem - if it's a client or server side, investigate it

Comment: @FlashThunder Okay, but where can I get to the log and check it?

Comment: write it yourself with `file_put_contents('log.txt',var_export($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);` or something like that

Comment: @FlashThunder okay, I will try it and write here what I'll have found out, thanks!

Comment: also check the size of column where are you storing info

Comment: Thanks @FlashThunder for your idea with a log, I found out that the characters that strip the messages are emojis such as . When an emoji occurs in a message, it gets deleted and stripped from that point onward. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score -2):

Thanks @FlashThunder for your idea with a log, I found out that the characters that strip the messages are emojis such as . When an emoji occurs in a message, it gets deleted and stripped from that point onward. Thanks for you help!